# SQLServer 2008: Stored procedure call from JAVA Returns error when both insert and update statement are executed

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, spring-mvc, java-stored-procedures

i call stored procedure in sqlserver2008 from Java

```
jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("User_Ip_Details");
output = jdbcCall.execute(input);
```

My stored procedure has an output parameter and an insert,update statement.
There is no issue in stored procedure.
After i execute the stored procedure, control goes to catch block and i get the below message

```
[JdbcTemplate] CallableStatement.execute() returned 'false' 
[JdbcTemplate] CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1 
[DataSourceUtils] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

i guess the insert,update statements returns some values and it causes the trouble.
 Please let me know what issue is occuring here and how to resolve this problem.

Comment: see if the procedure work in the SQLServer it self first or post the Procedure code

Comment: procedure works fine, no issue in that.i mentioned that in my post. the jdbc sp call isnt working fine with both insert and update statement in stored procedure. that is the issue

Comment: since it insert and update most likely you need transaction scope to run the java call

Comment: i'm not aware of that. please let me know how to do that, i will check and confirm

Comment: did you use spring template if that the case just annotate you method with @Transactional

Comment: i'm using Spring mvc. but i'm not sure what spring template is. i use new new  SimpleJdbcCall() -- object for stored procedure call

Comment: one thing use try catch and post the exception trace with your question

Comment: exception message returns null. i have posted the error message useful for analyzing this issue in my post

Answer (score 0):

add @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class) to you spring controller method or to the method that have you SimpleJDBC call

Comment: help me to understand what will introducing this annotation do to my issue?

Comment: what is your stacktrace wrap you code in try catch in the catch do exp.printStackTrace() , look to the server log and post the full stack trace

Comment: no enough information this link may be help you 
http://jhreview.com/tech-stack/questions/33025138/spring-stored-procedure-output-parameters-return-in-wrong-order